# Problem with logic for selecting multiple given choices in php mysql and html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I run in to problem (i am still beginner)

So the problem is i have 3 tables, first one its clotes (it have category row and town row), 2nd one is clotes_category(it have category_id and category_name), and the third one is towns(towns_id and towns_name)

So now on the front end i have dropdown from categories and will show the products form that category, and on the left side i have multiple towns, and when i select town i will get all from that town.

I am getthing them with $_GET and they have their own .php page (town_clotes.php?town_clotes=1) or (cat_clotes.php?cat_clotes=1)

But how to make when i will select (click on) town and get all from that town but then if i want to click on the category to show only that category from that town and vice-versa (was trying to understand the one to many and many to many concept but still i dont know how should i code it.

Should i make another .php page town_cat.php so i can get town_cat.php?town_cat= something and how to do this ...

if the question is confusing please write what is confusing and i will, try to explain more ...

Comment: If I knew what was confusing, I guess it wouldn't be confusing. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query. And what are clotes anyway.

Comment: its confusing - i think first you need to separate your front end issues from back end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way imho is to make only *one* receiving page.

On the sending page, collect the data from city and category (by putting them in one form or using some javascipt).
Then there are 3 options:

```
city = 1      , category = empty
city = empty  , category = 1
city = 1      , category = 1
```

Send that to the receiving page (like `page.php?town_clotes=1&cat_clotes=empty`) and apply some logic:

```
if(city !== empty && category === empty)
  return  only city
else if(city === empty && category !== empty)
  return  only category
else if(city !== empty && category !== empty)
  return  category from that city
else
  error
```